# Choose the person who worked the most night shifts

Tags: mysql

How do you choose the employee who has worked the most night shifts of all time? There are 2 tables, one with workers, the second with night shifts, in which 2 people work per shift.

Users:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Oliver |
| 2 | Harry |
| 3 | Jacob |

Hours:

| id | NightShift1 | NightShift2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | 1 | 2 |
| 7 | 1 | 3 |
| 8 | 3 | 1 |

Comment: Join the tables, then use `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY users.id` to get the number of times they worked. Finally, use `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1` to get the top.

Comment: You did not try anything yet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you can to essentially loop over the hours table twice; you do this by joining an ad hoc table specifying which shift you are looking at:

```
select users.id, users.name
from hours
join (select 1 position union all select 2) position
join users on users.id=if(position=1,hours.NightShift1,hours.NightShift2)
group by users.id
order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can UNION the `Hours` table on top of itself and then group by the user id to see who has the highest count:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as nightshiftcount,  userid 
FROM (
    SELECT NightShift1 as userid FROM Hours 
    UNION ALL SELECT NightShift2 FROM Hours
    ) as hrs 
ORDER BY nightshiftcount DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

If you need the name, you can just INNER JOIN to that table in that outer `FROM` clause and pull that column through.